# System.Windows.Media in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, silverlight

Can I use the " System.Windows.Media" in the ASP.NET MVC application.

Because I need to draw image using this.

Is it possible or we need to use System.Drawing only for the Web Application ?

Comment: Actually what is the exact requriement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to add a reference to the `PresentationCore` assembly.